# How to read a meter for radio and microwaves?

Tags: microwaves, radio-frequency

I am not clear on how to read this meter for radio waves and microwaves. The bottom band shows it measures from .01 to 1. First, I'm not sure what the units mean (mW/cm2). Radio waves are from 30KHz-300GHz. Microwaves are a subset of that, from 300MHz-300GHz. So what is 0.1 to 1? Second, is the meter measuring the frequency of the radiation or the amount? or both? If you point it at something emitting say 30Khz AND 299GHz, what will it read?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvkzk.jpg

Comment: By the way those are the units of intensity

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can answer most of your questions referring to the documentation:  https://www.trifield.com/products/trifield-meter-model-100xe/, but to summarize, it appears that the meter is measuring the flux of the radio/microwave energy detected by the meter, which is in units of power/unit area (milliWatts per square centimeter) in the frequency range of 50 MHz – 3000 MHz (3 GHz).  So it is essentially measuring the "amount" of radiation within that frequency range.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So the entire range for the device is 50 MHz – 3000 MHz (3 GHz). Microwaves are from 300MHz-300GHz. So this device can measure only microwaves from 300HZ-3GHz, missing out on the range of microwaves from 3GHZ - 300GHz? Modern microwave ovens operate at the frequency 2,450 MHz, so it sees that. Ok. What about my 30Khz AND 299GHz question. Do they just get summed up into the reading?

Comment: I guess it would need to be other numbers, like 51MHz and 2.99 GHz.